# NeuroPh Error won't diminish

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am creating a network for water level forecasting. I am using NeuroPh 2.91 for windows. I set the network to 3 inputs since it is accepting 3 inputs namely water level, rainfall, and inflow. I am using multi-layer perceptron, tanh as transfer function and backpropagation as learning rule with 9 hidden neurons.

I am always having this output:

```
Starting neural network training...
Training network try using data set adminshet
Training error: null
```

and the total network error according to the graph is 20,000+ .
What should i do? I am really new to ANN and Neuroph.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, but more a question how to use an existing program "NeuroPh".

Comment: Yes but there is no way to add the NeuroPH tag if you do not have 1500 reputation, it is why @jalusa could not add it and I added netbeans which is the IDE behind neuroph.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue here. Similar setup. It works for me, whe I strongly limit the Max-Iterations. e.g. to 10.
This makes me think, that there is a bug in the NeurophStudio.

Short Tip, which worked for me:
Do it yourself! Open Eclipse, add a Project, add the Neuroph jars and build your network. Its hard, but this works exactly as expected. You have to dump your own results into a csv file and display it with Excel. But ANN-handling doesn't work just by "clicking on a gui".

```
package de.sauer.dispe;

import org.neuroph.core.Layer;
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
import org.neuroph.core.Neuron;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSet;
import org.neuroph.core.transfer.Linear;
import org.neuroph.core.transfer.Tanh;
import org.neuroph.nnet.MultiLayerPerceptron;
import org.neuroph.nnet.learning.BackPropagation;

public class DirSpeCntrl {

    private static final int MAX_ITER = 2000;
    private static final double MAX_ERROR = 0.005;
    private static final double LEARNING_RATE = 0.1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Create ANN");
        NeuralNetwork<BackPropagation> nn = new MultiLayerPerceptron(3, 15, 15, 1);

        // Setting ALL neurons to TanH transferfunction (important, if you have negativ values)
        Layer[] layers = nn.getLayers();
        for(Layer curLayer: layers) {
            for(Neuron curNeuron: curLayer.getNeurons()) {
                curNeuron.setTransferFunction(new Tanh());
            }
        }

        for(Neuron curNeuron: layers[3].getNeurons()) {
            curNeuron.setTransferFunction(new Linear());
        }

        nn.randomizeWeights();

        System.out.println("Load Sampledata...");
        DataSet ds = DataSet.createFromFile(
                "C:\\Users\\meist_000\\Documents\\Thesis\\vanilla_eng.csv", 
                3, 1, ";");

        System.out.println("done: "+ds.getRows().size()+". Learn...");

        // Setting stuff
        BackPropagation lr = new BackPropagation();
        lr.setLearningRate(LEARNING_RATE);
        lr.setMaxIterations(MAX_ITER);
        lr.setTrainingSet(ds);
        lr.setNeuralNetwork(nn);
        nn.setLearningRule(lr);

//      bla.learn(ds); Faster bulk operation...

        // Slower single operation with logging:
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_ITER;i++) {
            lr.doLearningEpoch(ds);
            double curError = lr.getTotalNetworkError();
            System.out.println(curError);

            if(curError < MAX_ERROR) {
                System.out.println("Stopped on "+i);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Testing the network
        nn.setInput(new double[] {0.080484492, -0.138512128, -0.140826873});
        nn.calculate();
        double[] prediction = nn.getOutput();
        System.out.println("Pred: "+prediction[0]);
    }

}
```